# How to handle OAuth with Outlook REST API in client c# app?

Tags: c#, rest, email, outlook-restapi

I am trying to implement what's explained [here](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted) in a client (**edit: installed Win10 UWP**)application meant for Outlook.com users (no O365, no Azure). As explained in the [Mail API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations), the current client libraries are not ready to be used with regular Outlook.com users and the v2 app model, therefore I would love to learn how to call the REST APIs from a client app directly.

Specifically, a c# code sample on how to handle the login and permission request operation would be really appreciated. At the moment I know how to use a `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to send the GET request with the specified scopes, and how to open the web browser to let the user login, but after they grant their permission nothing happens because the browser does not know hot to handle the redirect uri, which seems to be a standard one for every installed app. As a result I don't know how to receive the response message with the authorization code in my app.

Could someone explain how to handle this situation to someone who is new to this kind of things like me?

EDIT: As I said above I'm trying to work on an installed app, not a web app. Of course the underlying logic of the problem is the same, but the libraries I can use might not be. Specifically I am working on a Windows 10 UWP app.

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/dotnet) on dev.outlook.com works with the v2 model and Outlook.com. The client library works fine with Outlook.com. It's the released versions of ADAL that don't work with the v2 OAuth model. The Azure team has put out an "experimental" library that does work though, and the client library for the Mail API will work with it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more clear, I am trying to implement that process in an installed app, not a web app. The logic of what I'm doing might be the same, but for example I cannot use `System.Web.Mvc`. Specifically I am experimenting on a Windows 10 UWP app.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of login without using a browser. We'll do it with outlook api and microsoft graph. We must first login and get token.

```
public class AccessTokenModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    }

public static string GetToken()
            {
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com");

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", 'yourAppId'),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", 'yourAppPassword'),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "emailAddress"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "emailPassword"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://graph.microsoft.com"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid")
                });

                var result = client.PostAsync($"/common/oauth2/token", content);
                var resultContent = result.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenModel>(resultContent.Result);

                return model.AccessToken;

            }
        }
```

Then we can use the services offered by outlook api.