# SMTP Send E-Mail Office 365 MustIssueStartTlsFirst

Tags: c#, email, office365, smtpclient, starttls

Im trying to send an email with the office 365 smtp, but im getting the following error:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57
> Client not authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.139
> Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect.
> [XXXX.XXXX.prod.outlook.com]

I noticed that some things got changed "recently" with the office 365 smtp and the most recent code, that I found, that works for most people was this:

```
SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();

mySmtpClient.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
mySmtpClient.Port = 587;
mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
mySmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
mySmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
mySmtpClient.TargetName = "STARTTLS/smtp.office365.com";
mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

// add from,to mailaddresses
MailAddress from = new MailAddress(email);
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(email);
MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);

// set subject and encoding
myMail.Subject = "Test message";
myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

// set body-message and encoding
myMail.Body = "<b>Test Mail</b><br>using <b>HTML</b>.";
myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
// text or html
myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

mySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
```

But Im still getting the same error as before (MustIssueStartTlsFirst).

Anyone know the problem?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806662/using-oauth2-to-send-email-via-office365-c-sharp and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477701/how-to-handle-oauth-with-outlook-rest-api-in-client-c-sharp-app . Also search for : `c# send email office 365 oauth` or `c# outlook oauth`